# nested if handle bars in meteor

Tags: if-statement, nested, handlebars.js

I have 3 users, I want to differentiate the navbars for each user.

Using nested handlebars I am able to write for three users but upon this if none of the users "default navbar" has top be displayed. I am not finding this anywhere. Can anyone help me in this?

The code I have written for three users differentiating the navigation bars and if some other user opens the other users it should show only registered user navigation bar as I have defined with the alanning:roles package.

Up to three users I am able to show and separate the headers and I need another else case to put default navbar if nobody signs in and views the page.

```
{{#if user1}}
    {{> a_header}}
    {{else}}
        {{#if user2}}
            {{> c_header}}  
        {{else}}
     {{> header}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
```

I did research and I got the following code for nested if else case:

```
**{{#if condition1}}
{{else}}
  {{#if condition2}}
  {{else}}
     {{#if condition3}}
     {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}**
```

From above code I need another else case for inserting default navbar. Please help me anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of nesting your conditionals, it would be *much* cleaner to *chain* them with an `else if`. Handlebars [supports](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals) this. Assuming your third conditional is `user3`:

```
{{#if user1}}
    {{> a_header}}
{{else if user2}}
    {{> c_header}}  
{{else if user3}}
    {{> header}}
{{else}}
    {{! TODO: Call default navbar partial here. }}
{{/if}}
```